# Does ncurses getch() with echo() on ensure that the character will be visible on the screen before the next statement in the program is executed?

Tags: c, echo, ncurses

I have an ncurses program that looks like this

```
1. int c =0;
2. initscr();
3. timeout(-1);
4. printw("Enter a character");
5. getch();
6. printw("\nOkay\n");
7. c = 5;
```

I would expect that the output of `getch()` as well as following `printw()` should happen (and be visible on the screen) before c is modified to 5. However this does not seem to be happening ( Using qemu-kvm and breaking at that point to verify). Is there any reason why this might be happening or some way to ensure the output being visible on the screen before the next statement is executed ?
does fflush(stdout) guarantee that ?

The OS is virtualized gentoo being run using qemu-kvm. The screen is in console mode ( X not initialized).

Comment: Buffering of output, like in plain c? If it's so  - there should be some kind of flush - here's something that might help http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=547801

Comment: @Anton yeah I am *guessing* buffering of output too, but how do I verify and correct that !

Comment: Changelog says that output gets flushed after wgetch() since version 1.8.2, do you have this version?

Comment: Also there should be intrflush() call with true parameter to flush the output, as http://linux.die.net/man/3/keypad says

Comment: I think the problem is because of the way gui update is handled by qemu which is at regular intervals.

Comment: Have you tried other oses or vms? on real hardware the issue is not reproduced?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably forgetting to issue the `refresh()` command. See the following example code which appears to work:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <curses.h>


int main(void) {

    WINDOW * mainwin;
    int c=0;

    /*  Initialize ncurses  */

    if ( (mainwin = initscr()) == NULL ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error initialising ncurses.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    timeout(-1);
    printw("Enter a character: ");
    getch();
    printw("\nC = %d Ok\n", c);
    c = 5;
    printw("C is now %d\n",c);
    refresh();
    sleep(10);
    /*  Clean up after ourselves  */

    delwin(mainwin);
    endwin();
    refresh();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```